# I need to figure out how to properly use variables/instance variables?

Tags: processing

```java
float x = 100;
float y = 100;
float p = 150;
float l = 10;
int r = 150;
int t = 100;
int s = 100;
int w = 60;
int h = 60;
int z = 11; 
int eyeSize = 10;
int pigNose = 30;
int pigBody = 30;
int pigEars = 35;
int pigTail = 20;
int speed = 1;

void setup () {
  size (600, 600);

}

void draw () {
  background(255);

   //Draw legs
  fill(255);
  rect(x+(2*w), y+h/3.5, z, 2*z);
  rect(x+(w), y+h/3, z, 2*z);
  rect(x+(1.5*w), y+h/3, z, 2*z);
   rect(x+(2.5*w), y+h/3.5, z, 2*z);


  ////draw body 
  fill(255);
  ellipse(2.1*x,y-pigBody, p, p-(2*l));

 //draw tail
 fill(0);
 line(2.85*x, y-pigTail, (6+l)*pigTail, pigTail*3);


   // Draw payer's head
  fill(255);
  ellipse(x,y-pigNose,t,t);

  // Draw player's eyes
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x-w/3+1,y-h/2,eyeSize,eyeSize);
  ellipse(x+w/3-1,y-h/2,eyeSize,eyeSize);

  //Draw nose
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x, y, pigNose, pigNose);

  //draw ears
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x-(w/2),y-h, pigEars, pigEars);

  fill(0);
  ellipse(x+(w/2),y-h, pigEars, pigEars);
}


  void mousePressed(){
  x = mouseX;
  y = mouseY;
  }
```

I'm not that great at using variables instead of magic numbers and I'm wondering why when I click somewhere on the screen the pig splits apart? I'm also supposed to be using instance variables but I'm not sure how.  Can anyone help? This is for Processing.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea by using `x` and `y` variables and basing all your shapes off those variables. But you got one thing wrong: you're **multiplying** those variables by different values to get the positions of your shapes, when you should really be **adding** to those variables to get the positions of your shapes.

Think about it this way, using a simpler example:

```
size(200, 100);

float x = 100;
float y = 50;

ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
ellipse(x*.8, y, 20, 20);
```

This creates a drawing of two circles next to each other:

[image: two circles]

That might seem correct, but now what happens if I change my `x` variable?

```
size(200, 100);

float x = 50;
float y = 50;

ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
ellipse(x*.8, y, 20, 20);
```

Since I'm multiplying my `x` value by `.8`, now that I change my `x` value to `50`, the second ellipse will be at `40`, which is only `10` pixels away from the first circle. But in the first sketch, the second ellipse was `20` pixels away!

[image: two circles]

Note that the same thing will happen if I increase `x`, the space between the circles will increase. This is what's happening in your example.

To fix this, I need to **add** values to my variables to get the locations of my other shapes:

```
size(200, 100);

float x = 150;
float y = 50;

ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
ellipse(x-20, y, 20, 20);
```

Now the circles will stay next to each other (in this case, `20` pixels apart) no matter what the value of `x` is.

[image: two circles]

You have to do something similar, just with two variables instead of one. If it doesn't make sense, try drawing your figure out on a piece of paper, and use a few different example values for `x` and `y`. What are the locations of the other shapes?

Also, you're already using instance variables. Those are just the variables at the top of your sketch. (Unless you're supposed to be using classes, but I doubt that's the case here.)

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot.